# property overriding not working in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, polymorphism, overriding

Here i have written `Special Customer class` which is `child class` and i
have `overridden Property Cname` where i want Special Customer can
change the Name only if they `Cname="Special"` but currently it's not
happening it is going to `base Cname property` which is checking balance
(which i don't want for `Special Customer class`) 
and pls let me know if i am achieving 
`Runtime Polymorphism` by this code

```
  class Customer
    {
       protected int _cid,_bal,_status;
        protected string _cnmae;

        public Customer(int _cid,int _bal,int _status,string _cname)
        {
            this._cid = _cid;
            this._bal = _bal;
            this._cnmae = _cname;
            this._status = _status;
         }
        public int Cid
        { //read only property
          get
            {return _cid;}

           }
        public virtual string Cname
        {
            get
            {return _cnmae;}
            set
            {
                if (_status != 0 & _bal >= 500)
                {_cnmae = value;}
            }
        }
        public int Bal
        {
            get
            {return _bal;}
            set
            {
                if (_status != 0 & value >= 500)
                { _bal = value;}
            }
        }
        public int Status
        {
            get{ return _status;}
            set
            {_status = value;}
        }
       public  virtual void display()
        {
          Console.WriteLine("id={0} and name={1} and balance={2} and status={3}", _cid, _cnmae,_bal,_status);
        }
  }

 class Specialcustomer:Customer
    {
        public Specialcustomer(int _cid, int _bal, int _status, string _cname) :base( _cid, _bal, _status,_cname)
        {
        }
        public override string Cname
        {
            get
            {return base.Cname}
          set
            {if (value == "SPECIAL")
                {
                    base.Cname = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void display()
        {
          Console.WriteLine("id={0} and name={1} and balance={2} and status={3}", _cid, _cnmae, _bal, _status);
        }
}
 class Program
    {        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer C1 = new Specialcustomer(10, 400, 1, "BOND");
            C1.display();
            C1.Cname = "SPECIAL";
            C1.display();
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to learn about automatically-implemented properties - you could save a *lot* of code here. I'd also suggest that if a property can't be set to a value, it's usually better to throw an exception rather than to just silently ignore the value.

Comment: (I'd also advise following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: pls stop -ve Voting !!

Comment: If you want people not to downvote, you should improve your question: 1) Format the code better. It's all over the place at the moment. 2) Reduce this to a [mcve] - there's a lot of irrelevant code at the moment. 3) Make your question much clearer in terms of what you expect to happen vs what actually happens. Your code is working absolutely as I'd expect it to: if you set the value to "SPECIAL" it calls the base setter; if you set it to something else, it doesn't. That's exactly what your overriding setter says to do. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: i want to Special Customer to don;t check bal and check Special Customer class Condition (Cname=Special) then only Change the name !!

Comment: Well it's currently checking the name, and then asking the base class to do whatever the base class normally does - which includes checking the balance. What did you expect `base.Cname = value;` to do? If you want it to *unconditionally* change the name if the name is `SPECIAL`, you'll need to have a different code path that change the name in the base class, e.g. a protected `SetCnameUnconditionally` method. That feels very odd though...

Comment: @JonSkeet then where is the overriding.i want to do achieve  property overriding

Comment: You're already doing overriding. Everything is working exactly as per normal inheritance and specialization. The extra code in my answer still overrides the property, but then uses the extra code path to unconditionally set the name (bypassing the balance check).

Comment: @JonSkeet atleast pls tell it's Runtime polymorhphism or not ?

Comment: Yes, it is. The overriding property is being called, just as you'd expect. The only reason the base property is then being called is that your overriding property is calling it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43314671/7011379 @JonSkeet pls tell if it's Runtime Polymorphism i get confused evrytime

Answer (score 1):

Your code *is* working already - it's calling the `SpecialCustomer.Cname` setter, as you can easily tell either by setting a breakpoint in it or adding some logging. (I just added a `Console.WriteLine` statement in the setter.)

However, it's not changing the value of `Cname` because of the condition in the `Customer.Cname` setter:

```
set
{
    if (_status != 0 & _bal >= 500)
    {
        _cnmae = value;
    }
}
```

If you change your code so that the balance of the customer is (say) 600 instead of 400, then `Cname` changes to `SPECIAL` as you'd expect.

If you want `SpecialCustomer` to change the name *unconditionally* if the value provided is `SPECIAL`, you'll need to add that functionality into the base class, e.g.

```
class Customer
{
    public virtual string Cname
    {
        get { return _cnmae; }
        set
        {
            if (_status != 0 & _bal >= 500)
            {
                SetCnameUnconditionally(value);
            }
        }
    }

    // This method allows subclasses to bypass the conditions
    // in the normal setter
    protected void SetCnameUnconditionally(string value)
    {
        _cnmae = value;
    }
}

class SpecialClass
{
    public override string Cname
    {
        get { return base.Cname; }
        set
        {
            if (value == "SPECIAL")
            {
                SetCnameUnconditionally(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know it's working but i't going to base property which i don't want.Otherwise there is no use of Overriding if it is checking the Base property Condition instead of overridden property(which it should be)

Comment: @DeepakJain: Your code explicitly calls the base property setter... but only if you set the value to "SPECIAL". Your code *is* setting the value to "SPECIAL", so it's then calling the base setter. It's working exactly as I would expect it to. If you set the balance to 600 but set Cname to "Not special" then it doesn't change. You really aren't being clear about the expect result vs the actual result.

Comment: if i Change the code from  base.Cname = value; to Cname=value in SpecialCustomer class it's throwing Stack overflow Exception

Comment: @DeepakJain: Well yes, it would. I never suggested changing it to that.

Comment: @DeepakJain: I've edited my answer to show how you'd do this unconditionally. It feels like a very strange subclass behaviour though...

Comment: @DeepakJain: The downvote isn't mine, but it could easily have been as your question is unclear. But *asking* people to remove a downvote isn't nearly as effective as improving the question. If you ask bad questions, you should expect downvotes.